# vue draggable almost works

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, rubaxa-sortable

I am using [vue draggable](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable). In my example I am trying to drag an some HTML by an element with a specific class.

```
<draggable :list="list" class="dragArea" :options="{draggable:'.dragg-me'}">
  <div class="draggable" v-for="element in list">
    <div class="dragg-me">dragg me</div>
    <div class="element">
      {{element.name}}
    </div>
  </div>
</draggable>
```

Here is the [full example](https://jsfiddle.net/hvxd25jt/).

I need to be able to drag by the div with the `dragg-me` class, but that is not working. Nothing happens when I do that. If I omit `:options="{draggable:'.dragg-me'}"` or if I set it to

```
draggable:'.draggable'
```

then of course it works again.

Is it possible to get it working the way I would like to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `handle`, [documented here](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable#handle-option).

```
<draggable :list="list" class="dragArea" :options="{handle:'.dragg-me'}">
```

Here is your fiddle [updated](https://jsfiddle.net/hvxd25jt/4/).