# How to use vuedraggable for an n x n grid of cells?

Tags: vuejs3, vuedraggable

I have taken a simple sample from [vue.draggable.next](https://github.com/SortableJS/vue.draggable.next) and converted it to use vuetify's `v-btn`. The resulting code works fine:

```
     <draggable
      :list="list"
      :item-key="name"
      class="list-group"
      ghost-class="ghost"
      :move="checkMove"
      :swap="true"
      @start="dragging = true"
      @end="dragging = false"
    >
      <template #item="{ element }">
        <v-btn  :class="{ 'not-draggable': !enabled }">
          {{ element.name }}
        </v-btn>
      </template>
    </draggable>
```

but in my actual app I don't want a simple word list; I am trying to use `draggable` for an array of images. But I don't know how to use the `<template #item="{ element }">` construction for this type of data:

```
<draggable 
      :list="trackGrid"
      :move="checkMove"
      :swap="true"
      :item-key="getIndex">
      <template #item="{ element }"  v-for="(row,r) in trackGrid">
        <v-row  no-gutters >
        <template v-for="(cell,c) in row" :key="r*8 + c" >
          <div>
          <v-col width="40">
                <v-img v-if=" !cell.used" class="canDragIt"
                :src = cell.content
                  >
                </v-img>
                <v-img v-else class="cannotDrag"
                  :src =  cell.content
                  > 
                </v-img>
          </v-col>
        </div>
        </template>
      </v-row>
  </template>
  </draggable>
```

The cell images show up with this code, but the last row of the grid is repeated eight times, rather than displaying each row differently. Also, the VSCode editor tells me that

> 'element' is declared but its value is never read

(and the same for the row/col iterators in `v-for`).

The grid renders correctly without the `<draggable>` component. So, what am I doing incorrectly here? How do I use the `{element}` construct, and/or what else am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. The problem was that the `draggable` iterator `<template #item="{ element }"  >` seems only capable of working in a column mode, not as rows, so is in effect incompatible with Vuetify's `<v-row>`. I had been trying to draw eight rows of images, with eight images in each row. What I am now doing is to draw eight columns of images , with eight images in each column:

```
<v-row  style="max-width: 320px;" no-gutters>
  <v-col width="40" v-for="n in 8">
    <draggable 
      :list="trackGrid[n-1]"
      group="track"
      :move="checkMove"
      :swap="true"
      :item-key="getIndex">
      <template #item="{ element }"  >
        <div>
          <v-img v-if=" !element.used" class="canDragIt"  :src = element.content />
          <v-img v-else class="cannotDrag"   :src =  element.content /> 
        </div>
      </template>
    </draggable> 
  </v-col>
</v-row>
```

This solution requires the rather odd prerequisite of 'inverting' the original array, so that rows become columns and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

I did not test the code but it seems that your syntax is incorrect.
Just add index which is `r` in your case and use element instead of row. Further more for vue draggable next most of the demos are incorrect. If you go through the help available on github and npm you will see the correct syntax for index and element.

And you have mixed vue 2 and vue 3 syntax for vuedraggable.

```
 `<template #item="{ element,index }">` is already iterating over each element.
```

I did not test just quick view that your code should be like this:

```
    <template #item="{ element,index }">
        <v-row  no-gutters >
        <template v-for="(cell,c) in element" :key="index*8 + c" >
          <div>
          <v-col width="40">
                <v-img v-if=" !cell.used" class="canDragIt"
                :src = cell.content
                  >
                </v-img>
                <v-img v-else class="cannotDrag"
                  :src =  cell.content
                  > 
                </v-img>
          </v-col>
        </div>
        </template>
      </v-row>
  </template>
```

And I am not sure about v-row and template syntax, just check it with normal div element in case if v-row/template does not work.

**Update:**
I also faced issues and decided to move away from vuedraggable and moved to the library [draggable plus](https://alfred-skyblue.github.io/vue-draggable-plus/demo/nested/) which is a new one and can be a good starting point than vuedraggable

[You can check demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-emzpry?file=src%2FApp.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FNestedComponent.vue)

Comment: The online help is indeed confusing. This page https://sortablejs.github.io/vue.draggable.next/#/simple uses the ` #item="{ element,index } syntax but this page https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-draggable-next does not. So which is best I wonder?`

Comment: Anyway, your suggestion has moved me forward, thanks - the images do now show in the correct places. But - if I drag a cell from row n to row n+1 (or n-1) the _whole row_ drags (and replaces the row moved into - this is sort of correct as I want 'swap' not 'sort'. If I try to drag sideways (to a different column) the whole row moves again but the drop isn't allowed (it just snaps back - maybe because the draged row now extends over the side of the grid. The editor is still saying that `index` and `c` are declared but never read, whic is odd because tehy are used in `:key`

Comment: here row is li and I guess you are breaking the row into cols then the quick fix should be like showing all cols in one nested list under row in another draggable , also use :v-modal props instead of :list, in this way you will be able to drag part of the row correctly, and will be able to sort and track the changes too. You can use move event to get the target or iterate over model to get the changes.

Comment: cols actually are another list which you specfied as one row not a sublist(or nested list) so when you drag it drags whole row as  there is no more list under single col so there is no need to treat your component as nested component you can just use another draggable to break cols into list and if you specify model you will have fresh state and you can save that state. You can use two of the events '@move, @change'

Comment: and for using class to stop dragging check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45314324/vue-draggable-almost-works?rq=2

Comment: thank you for your suggestions, The theory might be good but I'm finding it very difficult to translate into worlkng code. I did try `v-model` but the images disappeared. Also, there seem to be some bugs in `vue.draggable.next` and it's not well supported any more, so I'm experimenting now witha  different library

Answer (score 0):

I am not using vuetify but I had the same issue. The template should have a parent `HTML` tag and it fixed my issue. Something like this.

```js
 <template #item="{ element }" v-for="(cell,c) in row" :key="r*8 + c" >
  <div>
   *
   *
   *
  </div>   
 </template>
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you mean by a parent html tag - you haven't shown one in your code answer. Just adding a plain <div> doesn't do anything

Comment: This is the issue you are experiencing right? https://ibb.co/cKqYnSq

Mine is fixed by adding parent HTML tag or a wrapper HTML tag. It could be any HTML tag depending on your needs. And, inside the wrapper place your vuetify codes

Comment: Yes but I only got that issue after removing the `#item={element}` part. I knew i needed that but didn't know the correct syntax. Maybe I confused the issue by adding what happens when it's removed altogether, sorry. Anyway I have now moved on and will edit my question in a minute